# Will Windows 10 Anniverary Update's Dark Theme affect File Explorer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, themes, windows-10-v1607

I heard that the recent **Windows 10 Anniversary Update** will come with a optional dark theme

I would like to know whether this "Dark Theme" is really a theme, a theme that will affect the light resources of the user interface as the white **Explorer**'s background too, or is just the same "hidden" theming feature seen in previoues **Windows 10** versions that just will change to dark the *Universal Apps* and other minor things.

Note: I'm not asking for 3rd party themes, please focus only on the question I did.

Comment: you need to install a 3rd party desktop dark theme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is indeed the same 'theme' seen earlier, and it only affects UWX apps. Since win32 programs are in charge of their own coloration, the most that Windows can do is change the color of the title bar.
  And yes, Windows explorer will still be blindingly white. Scandalous.

Sources- installing the update and testing the darn thing myself

Comment: Win32 does define system colours (that it's up to apps to actually use).